# Which Album is Facebook Photo Located?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Based on the API of querying photos on Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

It doesn't seem like the Album ID in which this photo belongs is directly exposed?

How do you find out the Album ID of the album in which this photo belongs then?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, take the id of the photo and call the following FQL statement `SELECT aid FROM photo where pid={id you got from the Graph API photo object}`

Comment: yeah, the graph and fql objects aren't quite lined up on their properties.  Maybe one day Facebook will resolve this and fully hydrate the Graph objects with all of the properties.

Comment: Do you know if the photo location property is accessible under fql, 'coz it's not under the graph?